# how to call api controller from htttp client project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have 5 projects:

- Students.BBL (class library)
- Students.DAL (class library)
- Students.WEB (MVC project)
- Students.Client(class library, between WeB    and API)
- Students.API

How can I call API controller from WEB through Client?
Because when I call in Home controller (WEB) method from Client, it goes to client, and here I should create a request to API . But....

I don't know how to write a correct URL.
URL like this :

```
http://localhost:56543/api/students/4
```

doesn't work, it returns 404 error.

Code:

```
public StudentDTO find(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Base_URL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("student/" + id.ToString()).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CountryDTO>().Result;
            return null;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
```

private string Base_URL = "http://localhost:56543/api/";

Comment: Post your code that uses the HttpClient.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras fix the question

Comment: You just need to try something like http://localhost:56543/apicontroller/method/optional

Comment: @WilliamXifaras yes, I did the same thing but it didnt work

Comment: What does your route configuration look like?

Comment: @WilliamXifaras
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Can you browse to that API? Have you tried hitting it with PostMan?

Comment: @WilliamXifaras it doesnt work, dont understand why(

Comment: Check your spelling:  You mention the API is blah/api/students/6, but in your client code it's *student* rather than student*s*.

Comment: Could you show the api layer controller and action as well?

Comment: @Developer
Api layer:public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id)
        {
            stRepository.GetStById(id);
            return Ok(stRepository.GetStById(id));
        }

Comment: @Developer Action:public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            
            StudentDTO a = CC.find(id);
           
            return View(a);

        }

Comment: is it students or student your url has students/ and your code has student/ also test in a rest client like postman so you can compare results.

Answer (score 0):

From these comments you have in above posts:

- Api layer:public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id) { stRepository.GetStById(id); return Ok(stRepository.GetStById(id)); }
- "country" is a name of Api Controller

It seems like your route is wrong.
To resolve the route you expect - 
http://localhost:56543/api/students/4 , you should have

- ApiController named StudentsController
- That controller should have **one and only one** GET method which accepts an id as parameter - GetSomeMethodName(int id). In your case, you have GetStudent(int id). Make sure you dont have any other GET method in that controller with this signature. This point assumes that you havnt modified the default wep api route config.

If your controller name is "country" , then try http://localhost:56543/api/country/4.
Again this will throw error if you have multiple GET actions in country controller with the above signature.

**Cant resolve your problem unless you show your api controller code**

In case, you still wanna use country controller itself and you have multiple GET methods in that controller, then I would suggest attribute routing.

In web api config, add this:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

And in your api controller action

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~api/students/{id}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id) 
{  
    stRepository.GetStById(id); 
     return Ok(stRepository.GetStById(id));
 }
```

With the above configuration, you will get studen details in the route http://localhost:56543/api/students/4 - try hitting this URL from browser after keeping you API project running.

But I strongly suggest you to have Students controller instead on Country controller for getting student details